# PHP 5.4.30 mail() function gives Server Not Found Error for Gmail/yahoo Email id

Tags: php

I have upgrade my server **php version to 5.4.30**

When I use **mail()** with this version it send mails to other mail id like my company's webmail but when i use **Gmail/yahoo Email** it fails to send Email and gives **500 Internal Server Error**

**Code** :

```
<?php
$arr = array('myemail@company.com','myemail@gmail.com');
foreach($arr AS $key => $value)
{
    $to = $value;
    $subject = "Test Mail";
    $message = "<p>TEST</p>";

    $from = "senderemail@gmail.com";    
    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: <".$from.">" ;
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    //  It send mail to myemail@company.com this id
    // but for gmail id it shows error
}
?>
```

Comment: Internal server error will most likely write to your error log. Check there, and see if it gives any more info.

Comment: I doubt that PHP is doing this, it's mostly likely coming from yor mail software.

Comment: @Barmar is any problem with "\r\n" in headers?

Comment: No, that's normal. And you have that with both addresses, so it doesn't explain why some addresses work and others don't.

Comment: @Ashish - [The manual](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) states that `\r\n` is favoured (for the message) - "Each line should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n). Lines should not be larger than 70 characters." And headers to comply with [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html). Have you looked at the error logs yet?

Comment: A 500 Internal Server Error does not equal a "Gmail's Server Not Found" error. Check your error logs what's really going on!

Comment: To send mail via GMAIL or YAHOO or any of those type of email providers you have to be logged in to GMAIL/YAHOO etc before you send email. I think that basically means you have to use SMTP Which includes a login. You may have to use something like phpMailer in order to achieve sending mail via these providers. They also use non standard ports for mail transfer. Not sure why you are getting a 500 error but possibly its because your are not processing returned statuses properly from GMAIL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i change some setting from Server side..i add my site ip into server setting for Connectors and it works like charm again and save my head hair..

Answer (score -3):

```
<?php
ob_start();
$arr = array('myemail@company.com','myemail@gmail.com');
foreach($arr AS $key => $value)
{
    $to = $value;
    $subject = "Test Mail";
    $message = "<p>TEST</p>";

    $from = "senderemail@gmail.com";    
    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: <".$from.">" ;
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    ob_flush();
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: It looks like you've just added output buffering. Why would this help?

Comment: its not buffering output problem...it was happening because of my Server Problem..i change some settings and working fine now..